# How to get the values of each cell in an excel file then save it to mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, excel, xlsx

I'm using php and I used the simplexlsx.class to read an excel file. I can get all the values per row. However, I don't know how to get the values per cell so that I can save those values in a database.

I tried the following code to print the values per cell. But this is just for printing.

```
for($j=1; $j <= $xlsx->sheetsCount();$j++){

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $xlsx->rowsEx($j) );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

The $xlsx->rowsEx($j) is in an array form [name, value, href]. I am only interested with the value. Here's the code in simplexlsx.class for rowsEx.

```
function rowsEx( $worksheet_id = 1 ) {
    $rows = array();
    $curR = 0;
    if (($ws = $this->worksheet( $worksheet_id)) === false)
        return false;
    foreach ($ws->sheetData->row as $row) {

        foreach ($row->c as $c) {
            list($curC,) = $this->_columnIndex((string) $c['r']);
            $rows[ $curR ][ $curC ] = array(
                'name' => (string) $c['r'],
                'value' => $this->value($c),
                'href' => $this->href( $c ),
            );
        }
        $curR++;
    }
    return $rows;

}
```

How should I get the value? Your help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should read the cells and insert it to the database. You can uncomment the `var_dump` line if you which to see what is inside `$r`. Please note that the code does not check that the data is safe to insert in a database.

```
$mysql   = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

list($num_cols, $num_rows) = $xlsx->dimension();

foreach( $xlsx->rows() as $r ) {
    //var_dump($r);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `aTable` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`)
        VALUES ('" . $r[0] . "', '" . $r[1] . "', '" . $r[2] . "')";        
    mysql_query($sql);
}
mysql_close($mysql);
```